# System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary is not retaining saved settings after application restart

Tags: c#, settings.settings

I am trying to use the System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary to save paired values in to settings.settings file.

I run my application, updated the Settings, did Settings.Default.Save()
and when started the app again noticed the new settings did not work!

Looking in the created user.config, the StringDictionary was serialized
to `<value />`.

Please suggest me if there is any alternative or work around to make this work.

Comment: What if you run the exe without VS debugger?

Comment: @kennyzx :thanks for the response. tried by running the .exe directly from the bin\debug folder still the behavior is same as above.i.e until application is restarted values are getting saved and displayed back but when i restart the exe all stored values are vanished. Pls note here that always config file shows only <value/> tag inside.

Comment: I am able to resolve it by this way;SerializeAs.Binary has the trick.Added [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)] on top of the StringDictionary property of settings.designer.cs file.

Comment: you can post an answer to share your finding, and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

@kns provided the solution for me. I just added the line `[global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs(global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]` above the `StringDictionary` property in the `Settings.Designer.cs` file as follows:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs(global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
public global::System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary customSetPhrases {
 get {
            return ((global::System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary)(this["customSetPhrases"]));
        }
        set {
            this["customSetPhrases"] = value;
        }
    }
```

where `customSetPhrases` is the name of my setting. This seems to have done the trick.